# Ubuntu 14.04 screen corruption on live desktop (AMD 7970)

Tags: ati, system-installation, screen, screen-corruption

Ubuntu boots to desktop from the USB stick. There is no wallpaper, just black. The bar at the top of the screen is there and the launcher on the left. I can search in the dash, things look OK. Any program that is started results in a garbled screen. This is very odd, I have been using Ubuntu since 2006 and have it installed without error on my laptop. I have had many Linux distros installed on this Desktop and have never seen this error. I will record this and post it to Youtube see if we can't get some answers...

Here is a video of this error https://www.dropbox.com/s/7yknbxlvqz19fx7/2014-05-04%2013.58.38.mp4

Comment: I've had this problem to a lesser extent with a different AMD card. It went away as soon as I installed the AMD drivers from the software properties dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem should go away as soon as you install the proprietary AMD drivers (fglrx) from the *Additional drivers* tab in *Software & Updates*. Of course you need to be able to install Ubuntu first and be able to actually see those settings:

If you are using a regular Ubuntu DVD or USB-Stick press F6 in the boot menu and select nomodeset. If you are using UNetbootin select your boot entry and press TAB to edit the boot-options. Add *nomodeset* to the existing line and press ENTER to boot.

If you still get corrupted windows try the same with *vga=771* instead of *nomodeset*. Now you can install Ubuntu. Of yourse your installed version of Ubuntu will get the same corrupted windows, so for one single boot you need to add the boot-option that worked for you to the boot line in GRUB. You can edit the boot line by pressing *e*.

After you successfully booted into your fresh install, go to *Software & Updates* and select your driver like this:

[image: additional drivers dialog]

After a final reboot the corruptions should be gone.